# How to track history and correlation of emails?

Tags: outlook

Let me explain the background with an example. I receive an email from person1, I re-send this email to Person3 and Person2 waiting for a response. Person2 re-sends email to person4 who answers the email to person2; then, person2 emails the answer to me and, finally, I answer to person1.

Is there a way to "automatically" track and show all this sequence of mails in outlook? If yes, how?

For example I would like to see:

10-jan-11 15:00, I need a new computer, to: My name, from: person1

10-jan-11 15:30, I need a new computer, to: person2;person3,  from: My name

10-jan-11 17:00, xx needs a new computer, to: peson4,  from:person2

11-jan-11 08:00, There are not computers, to:person2,   from:person4

11-jan-11 08:10, Sorry, we have a used one, to:My name, from:person2

11-jan-11 09:00, Accept the used one meanwhile we buy one, to person1,  from:My name

Best regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each email message carries in itself a list of references (message-ids to which each of the forwards/answers applied). So if you were CC'ed on all those messages your email client could have re-constructed the whole thread. If you open the last email's source and check the headers you'll probably see the References: header with the list of all message ids involved (or Microsoft's Thread-index)

The problem is that you're not CC'ed on all those messages and each person in this thread sees only part of the thread. I don't think Outlook can show you the whole history unless you're always copied.

What is a general problem you're trying to solve?